# Possible to update a member for all objects in a collection using LINQ?

Tags: .net, linq, linq-to-sql

Say I have the code below that uses LINQ to SQL:

```
MyDataContext dc = new MyDataContext;
var items = from f in dc.TableName
            where f.ChildId == 4
            select f;
```

If the table TableName has a column called `Completed` is it possible for me to set the `Completed` column to `true` for everything selected above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to load the results of your query into a variable. You can then modify each object as you like, and then simply `SubmitChanges()`.

```
MyDataContext dc = new MyDataContext;
var items = dc.TableName.Where(f=>f.ChildId == 4).ToList();

items.ForEach(i=> i.Completed = true);

dc.SubmitChanges();
```